# opencv - OMR -Python - ordering issue

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, omr

I have written a script which should take a scanned image and check for survey results. I have managed to get it to identify the survey option boxes and identify which one has been checked on the page.

**Problem:** I would like to be able to identify which box has been ticked in terms of index. So in the example below i have options 1-5, number 2 is ticked, however for some reason the order of my boxes is mixed up in my list, in the console output it suggest that checkbox 5 is ticket. I need this to correctly tell me check box 2 is checked so I can then go on and store/analyse the information for the full survey

```
import os
import sys
import cv2

if os.path.isfile(file_path):

    # read the image
    img = cv2.imread(file_path, 1)
    # convert to gray
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # obtain inverse binary image
    _, binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
    # find contours
    _, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

    # select contours having a parent contour and append them to a list
    contour_list = []

    for h in hierarchy[0]:
        if h[0] > -1 and h[2] > -1:
            contour_list.append(h[2])

    print str(len(contour_list))+" contours found"

    # copy original image
    img2 = img.copy()

    a = 0
    # calculate the average size of contour and use this rough size for assuming we have a checkbox
    for j, i in enumerate(contour_list):
        a = a + cv2.contourArea(contours[i])
    mean_area = int(a / len(contour_list))

    boxes_found = 0
    options = 0
    answer = 0

    # draw those contours
    for cnt in contour_list:
        # if contour roughly matches our average size
        if (cnt > 0) & (cv2.contourArea(contours[cnt]) > mean_area):
            # print len(contours[cnt])
            options += 1
            answer += 1
            if len(contours[cnt]) > 210:
                # larger contour length signifies a tick
                cv2.drawContours(img2, [contours[cnt]], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
                print "option: "+str(options)+" ticked"
                # print str(options) + " options"
                # options = 0
            else:
                cv2.drawContours(img2, [contours[cnt]], -1, (0, 255, 255), 2)

            boxes_found += 1


    cv2.imshow('img2', img2)
    cv2.waitKey(0)

    print "Boxes found: " + str(boxes_found)

else:
    print "no file"
```

**Original image:**
[image]

**Current output image:**
[image]

**Console output:**

```
6 contours found
option: 5 ticked
Boxes found: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26017165/3803839) says that `findContours` finds the contours from the bottom of the image. So in a case like this, where the objects are ordered from left to right, you need to identify them based on their `x` coordinates.

Take the values you have in `[contours[cnt]]` in

```
cv2.drawContours(img2, [contours[cnt]], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
```

and the position in the order should come out fairly easily.